# iOSシミュレーターの動作が遅い

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

表題の通りですが、Swiftで、iOSアプリを開発していて、徐々にシミュレーターの動作が遅くなり、
設定のリセットや、シミュレーターにあるアプリを削除しても解決されません。

検索してもなかなか出てこないので、解決法をご教授いただきたいです。

Comment: この辺は、バージョンアップでかわるところですから、Xcodeのバージョンを明記したほうがいいでしょう。

Answer (score 6):

シュミレーターのDebugの所にSlowAnimationsがあると思うのですが、そこにチェックが入っていませんか？